# Ubuntu server on virtualbox

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I made virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 on it and made in automatically boot with Windows 8.1  using Task Scheduler with these settings :

- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run With highest privileges
- Hidden
- Triggers at startup
- Action is set to start a bat file with code

> "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe" -s "Ubuntu"

And i've set it to not automatically stop it.

So everything is working fine. Apache server starts everything works. Then after a while it doesn't respond like it's been turned off, but the process VBoxHeadless.exe is running. Apache, mysql, ssh etc. doesn't respond. Then i have to reboot the system and everything is fine, but it's kinda annoying. I'm pretty new to virtual machines + linux systems.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Have you checked server logs ? Are there any other services that are running on same port as of apache.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of things, but most generically, it sounds like a networking problem. It is likely a problem with how Ubuntu is obtaining it's network configuration and routes, and that probably points to dhcp if you are not statically assigning ip and routes.

Assuming dhcp, you might look to see if both virtual box and windows are each trying to answer the ubuntu dhcp request.  Or, perhaps you have a wireless hub responding, too?

You might try assigning a static IP and route if you don't want to tackle dhcp issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i gave it a static ip and now everything seems to be fine.